# How to securely grant WordPress write access to certain directories?

Tags: wordpress

Do I need to set the permissions to 775 or higher? At the moment, I can't do this, as apache runs as 'nobody'.

I use WHM/CPanel to administer the server.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 4):

If you set your server to use SuPHP and SuExec using EasyApache, that will secure the PHP.  You then wouldn't need global permissions for WordPress to write files as WordPress would be running as the cPanel user, thus you can set file permissions appropriately.

Answer (score 2):

I run a small collection of Wordpress installs on a VPS (granted, no WHM/CPanel, I do it the old fashioned way). Do yourself a favor and learn how to do it via FastCGI.  You can then isolate your WordPress installs to individual users and keep the directory permissions at 755 (or even tighter). The WordPress directories can then be owned by the same user that WordPress runs as and you'll not have to worry about odd permissions issues.

It's also a more secure method overall. Separation of privileges between unrelated applications is a wonderful concept.

Comment: Usually cPanel uses suPHP for privilege separation, it is a wonderful solution for that problem, because it runs PHP scripts as an account owner user.

Answer (score 0):

chown nobody.nogroup <directory wordpress needs to write to>